# не могу понять почему qopenglwidget не отрабатывает

Tags: qt, opengl

Pапихнул я qopenglwidget в главный виджет но почему то он не запускается.

Также я не могу использовать qt 3D и  Quick 3D

Вот тут код

**dialogokno.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOGOKNO_H
#define DIALOGOKNO_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QFile>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSize>

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QRect>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QSpacerItem>
#include <QObject>
#include "qopenglwidget.h"


class DialogOkno : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DialogOkno(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DialogOkno();

protected:
    QFile* file;         // загрузить файл
    QGridLayout* gl_layaout[4];
    QPushButton* b_load; // кнопка для выбора и загрузки файла
    QLabel* l_label[3];
    QLineEdit* le_edit[7];
    QSpacerItem* si_spacer[4];
    QOpenGLWidget *openGLWidget;

    //опен гл
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int width, int height);
};

#endif // DIALOGOKNO_H
```

**dialogokno.cpp**

```
#include "dialogokno.h"

DialogOkno::DialogOkno(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    // обявл элементы
    gl_layaout[0] = new QGridLayout(parent);
    gl_layaout[1] = new QGridLayout(parent);
    gl_layaout[2] = new QGridLayout(parent);

    gl_layaout[3] = new QGridLayout(parent);

    openGLWidget = new QOpenGLWidget(parent);

    l_label[0] = new QLabel(parent);
    l_label[1] = new QLabel(parent);
    l_label[2] = new QLabel(parent);

    le_edit[0] = new QLineEdit(parent);
    le_edit[1] = new QLineEdit(parent);
    le_edit[2] = new QLineEdit(parent);
    le_edit[3] = new QLineEdit(parent);
    le_edit[4] = new QLineEdit(parent);
    le_edit[5] = new QLineEdit(parent);
    le_edit[6] = new QLineEdit(parent);

    // настройки элеметов (стилизация)

    // заполнение элементов
    l_label[0]->setText("hla_global");
    l_label[1]->setText("hla_local");
    l_label[2]->setText("logger");

    le_edit[0]->setText("server_ip_global");
    le_edit[1]->setText("server_port_global");

    le_edit[2]->setText("server_port_local");
    le_edit[3]->setText("server_port_local");

    le_edit[4]->setText("log");
    le_edit[5]->setText("log_period_ms");
    le_edit[6]->setText("log_size_in_mb");

    //разложение элементов по группам

    gl_layaout[0]->addWidget(l_label[0], 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[0]->addWidget(le_edit[0], 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[0]->addWidget(le_edit[1], 2, 0, 1, 1);

    gl_layaout[1]->addWidget(l_label[1], 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[1]->addWidget(le_edit[2], 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[1]->addWidget(le_edit[3], 2, 0, 1, 1);

    gl_layaout[2]->addWidget(l_label[2], 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[2]->addWidget(le_edit[4], 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[2]->addWidget(le_edit[5], 2, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[2]->addWidget(le_edit[6], 3, 0, 1, 1);


    gl_layaout[3]->addLayout(gl_layaout[0], 0, 0, 1, 1);

    si_spacer[0] = new QSpacerItem(120, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    gl_layaout[3]->addItem(si_spacer[0], 0, 1, 1, 1);

    gl_layaout[3]->addLayout(gl_layaout[1], 0, 2, 1, 1);
    si_spacer[1] = new QSpacerItem(120, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
    gl_layaout[3]->addItem(si_spacer[1], 0, 3, 1, 1);
    si_spacer[2] = new QSpacerItem(20, 82, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    gl_layaout[3]->addItem(si_spacer[2],1, 0, 1, 1);
    gl_layaout[3]->addLayout(gl_layaout[2], 2, 0, 1, 1);
    si_spacer[3] = new QSpacerItem(20, 82, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    gl_layaout[3]->addItem(si_spacer[3],3,0);
    gl_layaout[3]->addWidget(openGLWidget, 1, 1, 3, 3);

    this->setLayout(gl_layaout[3]);
}

DialogOkno::~DialogOkno()
{

}

void QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
}

void QOpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f (0.51, 0.51, 0.51);
    glVertex3f (-0.51, 0.51, 0.51);
    glVertex3f (-0.51, -0.51, 0.51);
    glVertex3f (0.51, -0.51, 0.51);
    glEnd();

 }

void QOpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dialogokno.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    DialogOkno w;

    QDesktopWidget desktop;
    QRect rect = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen()); // прямоугольник с размерами экрана
    QPoint center = rect.center(); //координаты центра экрана
 
    qDebug() << "rect.x()/2 " <<rect.y()/2  << "rect.y()/2" << rect.y()/2;
    qDebug() << "center.x()/2 " <<center.y()  << "center.y()/2" << center.y();

    w.resize(center.x(), center.y());
    w.setWindowTitle("программа");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**dialog_okno_qmake.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2021-11-24T16:28:03
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = dialog_okno_qmake
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        dialogokno.cpp

HEADERS += \
        dialogokno.h


INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glfw_bin/include/GLFW/ \ # добавляем для удобства чтоб напрямую писать
               $$PWD/glew_bin/include/GL/  \  # только название заголовчного файла без полного пути
               $$PWD/stb_image/

HEADERS += \
    glfw_bin/include/GLFW/glfw3.h \
    glfw_bin/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h \
    glew_bin/include/GL/glew.h \

# --- linux ---

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglut

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLU

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
```

[image: Screenshot_20211129_165752.png]

**output** :

```
Запускается /home/dima/dima_project/dialog_okno_qmake/dialog_okno_qmake...
rect.x()/2  0 rect.y()/2 0
center.x()/2  515 center.y()/2 515
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x59b7a92e99a0
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
/home/dima/dima_project/dialog_okno_qmake/dialog_okno_qmake завершился с кодом 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем это такая ошибка которая выпрыгивает в астра линуксе.

вот тут ответ (https://wiki.astralinux.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=43614493 )

Я воспользовался первым вариантом

```
#include "dialogokno.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ForceRasterWidgets, false);
    DialogOkno w;

    QDesktopWidget desktop;
    QRect rect = desktop.availableGeometry(desktop.primaryScreen()); // прямоугольник с размерами экрана
    QPoint center = rect.center(); //координаты центра экрана

    qDebug() << "rect.x()/2 " <<rect.y()/2  << "rect.y()/2" << rect.y()/2;
    qDebug() << "center.x()/2 " <<center.y()  << "center.y()/2" << center.y();

    w.resize(center.x(), center.y());
    w.setWindowTitle("программа");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

добавил строку

```
       QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ForceRasterWidgets, false);
```

Всё заработало :3